# What does the dot mean when creating alias or criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

For example with the following code:

```
// Setup Criteria and aliases
DetachedCriteria criteria = forClass(Data.class)
        .createAlias("dataPointGroups", "dataPointGroups");

// Setup Restrictions
criteria.add(eq("dataPointGroups.id.groupId", groupId)).add(eq("archived", false));
```

Can explain what dataPointGroups.id.groupId is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot(s) here denote a property path expression.

**You should read `dataPointGroups.id.groupId` as:**

The `dataPointGroups` is a property of `Data` class (the property name suggests a one to many relationship from `Data` to a `DataPointGroup` entity.

That `DataPointGroup` entity class further has an `id` property. Probably that `id` property is an embedded primary key (judging from the name of the property `id`, mapped with `@EmbeddedId`).

In any case, the class type of that `id` property further has a property named `groupId`.

Hope my explanation is clear.

Anyway, this is how the entities and mappings may look like:

```
@Entity
class Data {
    @Id
    long id;        

    @OneToMany
    Set<DataPointGroup> dataPointGroups;
} 

@Entity
class DataPointGroup {
    @EmbeddedId 
    DataPointGroupPkClass id;
}

@Embeddable
class DataPointGroupPkClass {
    long groupId;
    long someOtherProperty;
}
```